# import UIkitに赤線が引かれている

Tags: swift, xcode7

下記のような状況になっているのですが、これはどのような状況でしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このままimport UIKitしても利用することはできるのですが、心配になり質問させていただきました。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家のstackoverflowで同じ内容のQAが見つかりました。
[Xcode 7.3: import Module displayed with strikethrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180575/xcode-7-3-import-module-displayed-with-strikethrough)
単なるバグでSwift2.2.1にはその修正が含まれるはずとのことです。("2016-04-12-a developer snapshot"にもその修正が含まれていると書いてありますが、snapshotビルドは他のバグを含んでいたり一部の機能が未完成であったりします。そもそもsnapshot版でビルドしてもApp Storeには提出できないので、実際のアプリの開発には使わない方が良いでしょう。)

要は「バグなんで修正版が出るまで無視してください」ということですね。